Does Russel's Paradox apply to predicate logic also?
In short, Russel's Paradox for Naive Set Theory (i.e., the fact that the question of whether "the set containing all sets that do not contain themselves" contains itself leads to a contradiction) inspired people to develop formal set theories like ZF(C).
Is predicate logic or first-order logic also susceptible to this paradox? I.e., let's define a predicate P(x) := "x is a predicate which is not true of itself". There are such predicates, i.e. while the predicate A(x) := "x is a predicate" is true of itself, the predicate B(x) := "x is a cat" is not true of itself. So P(A) is false, and P(B) is true. What is P(P)?
If this is a problem for predicate logic: how is it usually solved? Is there some logic theory that is to predicate logic like ZF is to naive set theory?
If not: why not; where is my example going wrong?

In High-order logic we have predicates of predicates, but they are organized into levels, or types.
Thus, a predicate of type n+1 will be applied to predicates of type n. This means that a formula like P(P) is not syntactically correct.
See also the discussion in Wittgenstein's Tractatus regarding the logic of Principia Mathematica and the Theory of types:
3.333:

A function cannot be its own argument, because the functional sign already contains the prototype of its own argument and it cannot contain itself.
If, for example, we suppose that the function F(fx) could be its own argument, then there would be a proposition “F(F(fx))", and in this the outer function F and the inner function F must have different meanings; for the inner has the form ϕ(fx), the outer the form ψ(ϕ(fx)). Common to both functions is only the letter “F”, which by itself signifies nothing.

This means that Russell's paradox, amounting at : R(R) iff not-R(R) is a violation of the syntactical rules of the formalized language, because the rules prohibit that a function of "level" n can be an argument of a function of the same "level".
See also 3.332 :

No proposition can say anything about itself, because the propositional sign cannot be contained in itself (that is the “whole theory of types”).

See also this post for some technical details.

Thanks! So my thought (i.e. having predicates talk about predicates on the same level) is the equivalence to naive set theory, and predicate/first order logic (or rather only higher-order logics being allowed to talk about the predicates of lower-order logics) is the answer to that problem. Re-reading even the introductory Wikipedia page with that in back of the mind answers the question already, I guess: First-order logic uses ... variables over non-logical objects with non-logical objects presumably being all mechanisms of first-order logic itself, including predicates.

@AnoE - ".. non-logical objects presumably being all mechanisms of first-order logic itself" not exactly. It means that in first-order arithmetic variables refer to numbers; in first-order set theory variables refer to sets*. In second-order arithmetic predicate variables refer to properties (sets) of numbers, and so on.

But you can use set theory to deal with formal languages, in which case you have symbols and strings of symbols: expressions and formulas, in which case the variables refer to syntactical entities: predicates, formulas, etc. And you can use f-o arithmetic also, through arithmetization.
